# How to validate TextFormField individually using onFieldSubmitted

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making a custom TextFormField Widget which will be used multiple times. How do I validate a single TextFormField without validating any other TextFormField that are in the same list/row/column.

```
Widget timeTextField (TextEditingController controller){
       return TextFormField(
         controller: controller,
         validator: (String userInput){
           if(userInput.isEmpty){return 'Need to input time';}
         },
         onFieldSubmitted: (String userInput){
           setState(() {
             debugPrint(userInput);
             controller.text = "amout";
             debugPrint(controller.text);
         });

   },
   );
 }
```

It validates when the user presses submit on the keyboard, if the TextFormField is empty it sends a validation error only to that TextFormField which the user pressed submit on.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Validation in `TextField`s happen based on the `Form` they are placed in (and not `Column` or `Row` or `List`). To validate TextFields separately put them in different forms, assign different keys and call `_formKey.currentState.validate` separately.

```dart
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final GlobalKey<FormState> _form1Key = GlobalKey();
    final GlobalKey<FormState> _form2Key = GlobalKey();
    final GlobalKey<FormState> _form3Key = GlobalKey();

    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Form(
            key: _form1Key,
            child: TextFormField(
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) return "Cannot be empty";
              },
            ),
          ),
          Form(
            key: _form2Key,
            child: TextFormField(
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) return "Cannot be empty";
              },
            ),
          ),
          Form(
            key: _form3Key,
            child: TextFormField(
              validator: (value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) return "Cannot be empty";
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
        _form2Key.currentState.validate();
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Just for information on a closed question:

You can use `autovalidateMode`.

This has currently 3 modes. We used to have `autovalidate` which is depreciated. This works only on FormFields and inside Forms.

**Example**

```
       TextFormField(
                  autocorrect: false,
                  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                  cursorColor: Colors.black,
                  key: _usernameKey,
```

**Reference**

- Flutter official [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/form-field-autovalidation-api)